# React Native iOS Sentry - Too many arguments to block call, expected 1, have 3

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Trying to build my React-Native app for iOS. Previous build was fine, but since I added Sentry for error logging, I can not build it. Linking was fine, I did it and it was successful.

I am getting this error:

```
Too many arguments to block call, expected 1, have 3
RNSentry.m
```

inside this part of code:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(sendEvent:(NSDictionary * _Nonnull)event
              resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
              rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul), ^{
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:event]) {
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:event
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:nil];

        SentryEvent *sentryEvent = [[SentryEvent alloc] initWithJSON:jsonData];
        [SentryClient.sharedClient sendEvent:sentryEvent withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (nil != error) {
                reject(@"SentryReactNative", error.localizedDescription, error);
            } else {
                resolve(@YES);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        reject(@"SentryReactNative", @"Cannot serialize event", nil);
    }
});
}
```

on this line:

```
reject(@"SentryReactNative", error.localizedDescription, error);
```

I am using RN version `0.59.9` and React version is `16.8.3`

Tried to google if someone had similar issues but found nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i has same issues like you. After I struggled for a few days I replace it by installing it manually .This error occurs because when we install react-native-sentry through the pod we will also install the pod react too.